# Three-term arithmetic progressions ending with a given prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

A student has asked me whether the following is true:

If *p* is prime and bigger than 37, there exists a three-term arithmetic progression of primes ending in *p*.

For smaller odd primes one can find 3-APs except for 3, 5, 13, and 37. For those the best one can do is (1,(p+1)/2,p). The next prime such that (p+1)/2 is prime is 61, but we can find a 3-AP (13,37,61).

(Edit) I have tested all primes up to 10^5 and found no other exceptions.

Any hints?

Comment: Is there any reason to imagine that this has a sensible solution?  Of course, for any particular $p$, it's just a search.

Comment: It seems a reasonable question, but I have no idea whether it is accessible.

Comment: I can't imagine that there are any tools to attack this with.  I suggest:  do a search of the first $1000$ primes, or so.  I wouldn't rely on evidence from small primes as there are a lot of small primes.

Comment: Already done, of course.

Comment: This seems to be a problem of similar difficulty as the Goldbach conjecture. Given $p$, there are about $p/12$ possible arithmetic progressions to consider (since the common difference must be a multiple of $6$); if the primes are distributed randomly, there's about a $1/(\log p)^2$ chance that the other two terms are both prime. So the number of such 3-APs should be about $p/12(\log p)^2$ when $p$ is large. (possibly with a modified constant as in the Goldbach conjecture, but I'm not sure that happens here)

Comment: Considering your search limit, my guess is that every larger prime allows such a solution but a proof of this conjecture will be out of reach.

Comment: A closely related result is the [Green-Tao theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem).

Comment: No further exception upto the prime $$p=1\ 446\ 822\ 739$$ Difference in the "optimal" solution is never larger than $$6\ 450$$

Comment: Consider three primes in arithmetic progression. $p_1+a=p_2, p_3-a=p_2$. Then $p_1+p_3=2p_2$ which is just Goldbach's conjecture, which posits there is a solution for any preselected $p_2$. The novelty here is that OP conjectures you can find a solution for any preselected $p_3$.

Comment: It looks like for all odd numbers $n$ greater than $37$, not just primes, (at least, up to $10,000,000$), primes exist such that $2p_2-p_1=n$ and $p_1<p_2<n$. If this was true for all odd numbers greater than $37$, this would imply that your statement is true.

Comment: I do not think that this conjecture is implied by some other open , but very likely true conjecture. For the primes, I arrived at a search limit of $3\cdot 10^9$ with no further exceptions.

Comment: OEIS sequence [A216495](https://oeis.org/A216495) makes this same conjecture.